# iOS: Draw clear circle with UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

In my `UITableViewController`'s cells, I want to display a circle with a number in it. I am using `UIBezierPath`'s `bezierPathWithOvalInRect:` to draw the circle.

Unfortunately, while I can set the `fill` color to be `clearColor`, the unused portion of the `CGRect` passed to `bezierPathWithOvalInRect:` is black.

How do I get rid of the black area created?

Partial screenshot for reference:
[image: Screenshot]
(I eventually hope to get that number inside the circle)

Code:

#### LTTTableViewCell:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // Create a square view using the height of the cell
    CGRect positionFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.height, self.bounds.size.height);
    LTTDrawBallView *drawBallView = [[LTTDrawBallView alloc] initWithFrame:positionFrame];
    [self.contentView addSubview:drawBallView];
}
```

#### LTTDrawBallView:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Create a new rect with some padding  
    // + create a circle from this new rect:
    CGRect box = CGRectInset(self.bounds, self.bounds.size.width * 0.1f, self.bounds.size.height * 0.1f);
    UIBezierPath *ballBezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:box];
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];
    [[UIColor greenColor] setFill]; // Green here to show the black area
    [ballBezierPath stroke];
    [ballBezierPath fill];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; // Happens with and without this line
}
```

Comment: Perhaps set the `opaque` property of the view to `NO`? I could also imagine that the black background isn't the view you're drawing, but the view behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the init method of your LTTDrawBallView, include the code:

```
self.opaque = NO;
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```