# Convert from swift to objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, swift2, xcode7

Guys can you please help me to convert this swift code to objective-c:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class PushTheButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    @IBInspectable var isAddButton: Bool = true

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
        fillColor.setFill()
        path.fill()

    }

}
```

and where should I put the code? is it in the header or implementation?
I would appreciate it if you could help me?

Comment: checkout this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115639/ios-draw-clear-circle-with-uibezierpath-bezierpathwithovalinrect)

Answer (score 2):

There will be two files on obj-c: header and implementation:

"PushTheButton.h"

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface PushTheButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor *fillColor;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable BOOL isAddButton;
@end
```

"PushTheButton.m"

```
#import "FSView1.h"

@implementation PushTheButton

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.fillColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.isAddButton = YES;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect];
    [self.fillColor setFill];
    [path fill];
}

@end
```